# Div height issue on aligning table to right

Tags: html, css

Following is my div CSS which was working fine before I added this table attribute inside my div container: `<table align="right" />`. After adding this my div container height got squeezed and the table inside it overflowed the div. Here is the sample image: 
[image]

Please help me with this issue.

Here is my CSS:

```
.grey-container
{
 background-color: #F5F5F9;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #F5F5E6;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px 20px 20px 20px;


}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div class="grey-container">
           <span style="color: #7E7E7E; font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold;">Add Quality Measure</span>

              <div style=" margin-top:5px;">
              <table align="right" class="table-padding" width="350" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td width="200" align="right"><span class="grey-h1" >Quality Measures</span>
              </td>
              <td width="150">
              <select>
              <option>Diabetes - HbA1c</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>
              </td>
            </tr>


            </table>
              </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: never use align it has been deprecated

Comment: @Deadlock http://jsfiddle.net/y9NQq/

Comment: just give table element margin-top 12px

Comment: @user2568107 align has not been deprecated. Where is your source of information?

Comment: @user2304394 http://jsfiddle.net/y9NQq/1/

Comment: @user2304394 works fine for me on jsFiddle. Looks exactly the same, only aligned right.

Comment: Someone told me on this site

Comment: Now check to this demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohit_azad/52rzk/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `overflow:hidden;` to your `grey-container` class.

Here's fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/e3Csf/

Here's a bit more on "overflow:hidden" magic:

http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

I created one `css` and this apply your **inner div**

```
.otherDiv{overflow:hidden;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="grey-container">
           <span style="color: #7E7E7E; font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold;">Add Quality Measure</span>

              <div class="otherDiv">  // add here class
              <table align="right" class="table-padding" width="350" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td width="200" align="right"><span class="grey-h1" >Quality Measures</span>
              </td>
              <td width="150">
              <select>
              <option>Diabetes - HbA1c</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>
              </td>
            </tr>


            </table>
              </div>
         </div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohit_azad/52rzk/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add some jquery:

```
$('.grey-container').height($('.grey-container').outerHeight() + $('table').height());
```

[jsfiddle.net/Hive7/y9NQq/3](http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/y9NQq/3)

make sure you have a js file though